# XAMPP Servers not starting in Macos Sierra

Tags: xampp

I have installed XAMPP in OS EL Captian, it works fine there. When i upgrade my os to macos Sierra, it throws the following error messages in XAMPP control panel...

> Restarting all servers...
>
> Starting MySQL Database...
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/mysql/scripts/ctl.sh : mysql  started at port 3306
>
> Starting Apache Web Server...
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/apache2/scripts/ctl.sh : httpd started
>   Starting ProFTPD...
>
> Exit code: 8
>
> Stdout:
>
> Checking syntax of configuration file
>   proftpd config test fails, aborting
>
> Stderr:
>
> MM-SHANMUGAM-SA.local proftpd[19886]: warning: unable to determine IP address of 'MM-SHANMUGAM-SA.local'
>
> MM-SHANMUGAM-SA.local proftpd[19886]: error: no valid servers configured
>
> MM-SHANMUGAM-SA.local proftpd[19886]: Fatal: error processing configuration file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/proftpd.conf'

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem. I didn't get the error though.

With me the problem was that Apache was already running on macOS itself so it couldn't start from XAMPP. I guess the update to Sierra must have started it.

I fixed the problem by stopping Apache by running `sudo apachectl stop` on the Terminal.